# Calling recover() on the acos table

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a default way to call recover() on the acos tree or do I have to create a model for it?

I looked and didn't see a recover() function under $this->Acl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a model and was able to successfully rebuild the lft and rght columns with a recover() call.